# Large database migration 120GB with downgrade of MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've got a large database of around 120GB that was migrated to temporary server a couple of weeks ago in a hurry. I should add I'm not a DBA by any stretch.

Unfortunately it was SQL 2017 rather than the original 2016 which has then caused an issue when trying to migrate it back to 2016. i.e it's not possible to migrate with drop/reattach or backup/restore.

I've tried scripting the database but as a couple of tables are 80% the size of the database it fails to import.

I've also tried APEX SQL Data Diff but I get "transaction log full" fail messages, even though transaction logging is set to simple.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to migrate this database back to the original server in a timely fashion.

Comment: You're going to need to script everything I'm afraid. I'm sure a search of "script all object definitions SQL Server" will yield some good results on your preferred search engine. Then you'll need to copy the data by means highlighted in the below answer: BCP, Bulk insert, SSIS, etc. I suggest doing to process in batches; if you have an especially large table then doing it all in one go is probably going to flood your transaction log, and any failures will put you right back to step 1 if you try and do the whole thing in one go.

Comment: Hppefully, however, you'll at least learn from this experience and be vigilant of the version of SQL Server you're using going forward. We all make mistakes (I'm not suggesting you were the one who installed the wrong version of SQL Server), however, taking ownership and learning from them is the important thing when we do.

Comment: I was the one who installed it unfortunately. Out of the 100 or so migrations I've done this is the only one that's been backwards. This is right at the top of my list of things not to do again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS or Export/Import wizard in SSMS to transfer the data from the old database to the new one. Or to export the data from 2017 to flat files and use [bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to import these filat files into 2016.